# How to remove \n from stored procedure input in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to add two columns and pass that result to other column.
I have a Lookup activity, For each and Stored Procedure.
The output of Lookup activity is input to For each and the output of for each is input to Stored Procedure.
[image: Output of Lookup activity]
The output values of Lookup activity and For Each don't have \n in their outputs. But the stored procedure input is taking \n as input.
[image: Input to Stored procedureaz]

Comment: Generally, when converting json to a string, the escape character `\n` will also be added.

Comment: @Harris Xu. Can we remove \n in the input of Stored Procedure.

Comment: Can you try to use `json()` function to convert string type to json type? It will remove the escape character.

Comment: Hi @Ravali, can it work now?

Comment: Hi @Harris Xu. I'll try it now.

Comment: @Harris Xu But the output of Lookup is not having \n.  Even for each is also not having the \n. inside for each I am having stored procedure. Only input to stored procedure is taking as \n.

Comment: This may be when input to stored procedure, this json object is coerced into a String object.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

1. I assign a json string to the string type variable via `@string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow)`, it will add some escape characters as follows:
   [image]
2. Then I convert the string to json type via `@json(variables('Arra1'))`
   [image]
3. The input of the Stored procedure is as follows, it will remove the escape characters:
   [image]